# haw to get wan ip for my machine programatically with vs 2008 c#

Tags: c#-3.0

How can I get the wan IP address for my machine programmatically using C# vs2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get *internet* IP ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515436/how-to-get-internet-ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string getdata()
{ 
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    String externalIp = utf8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"));
    return externalIp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution (the function gets my external IP address)

This is the function:

```
public string getdata()
{
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    String externalIp = utf8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp"));           
    return externalIp;
}
```