# Find correct Ip address returned by Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, .net, networking, dns

Suppose there are 2 computers on same network, named com1 and com2.

On com1, if I call

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("com2")
```

surely enough, it returns only 1 ip address, like 192.168.1.2,  which I could use it to communicate with com2. However, if I call

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("com1")
```

It will return *all* ip addresses (192.168.1.1(the one I want) as well as other addresses like 169.254.100.50 (vm address, I need to filter this out))

The question is, how can I get a unique "real" ip address for com1 in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't they all "real" IP addresses?  Which one do you want?

Comment: Yes, its so true. I want the ip address on the network. Which is the address accessible from com2 to com1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research this question is actually hard to answer. If "com1“ has multiple NICs, it is hard to find which NIC it uses to communicate with "com2", I have found [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515436/how-to-get-internet-ip) to get address on NICs that are connected to internet, VM address will not connect to internet. Obviously asking “com1" itself to find which NIC it uses to connect to "com2" is hard,should rather asking "com2" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then can you check the firewall settings of the "com2" or test it by turning it off.

Comment: Apart from they are obsoleted, they are returning all IPV4 addresses which has vm machine network interface addresses that is not accessible from com2

Comment: This does not answer my question.