# How does a client communicate with a Windows Service on a machine with multiple adapters?

Tags: c#, windows-services, dns

I've inherited a Windows Service + Client application written in C#. The Windows Service opens a TCP/IP socket for listening as follows:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPHostEntry iphe = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(iphe.AddressList[0], ExportServiceRequest.DefaultPort));
socket.Listen(2);
// Wait for incoming connections and Accept them.
```

while the client connects as follows:

```
using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    IPHostEntry iphe = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(iphe.AddressList[0], ExportServiceRequest.DefaultPort);
    socket.Connect(ep);
    // Talk to the server
}
```

The problem is that on certain machines with multiple network adapters, the 'wrong' adapter is picked by Dns.Resolve(), and the client connection fails.

I am aware that this code is aged and reeking, and haven't coded much raw socket code. Is there a best way to implement a Windows Service listening on a socket, such that at least local connections (from within the same machine) always succeed, regardless of how many network adapters the machine has?

Edit: my question appears poorly formulated. At the end of the day, I want the Windows Service to be accessible by a client, which always is running on the same machine, with no need for configuration. To anthropomorphize, I want the Windows Client to just yell at the server, "what IP address can I talk to you, oh Service running on TCP port ExportServiceRequest.DefaultPort on $LOCALHOST$? I want to talk to you", and have the ensuing TCP/IP conversation just work.

Comment: Title sounds like the start of a really poor programmers joke xD

Comment: Assuming that the service is running on a single machine, and the `Dns.Resolve()` issue you refer to happens on the client, then the issue appears to be with your DNS settings.  That said why is the client code not just using something like `IPHostEntry iphe = Dns.Resolve(SERVER_NAME);`?

Comment: er he has? the whole dns.gethostname() im guessing is the part which youve written as SERVER_NAME

Comment: @RhysW: exactly; I don't want to burden the user of the client program with having to configure this. I want the client to have a reliable way to talk to the server. Do I really have to bind to *all* the interfaces in the Server to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515436/how-to-get-internet-ip/515449 could be of use to you @JohnKallen

Comment: Dns.GetHostName `Gets the host name of the local computer.` so how exactly do you expect it to find the server?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: The client will *always* be running on the local computer.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the question then. I've +1'd it so that hopefully someone else can pitch in.

Comment: i think @Josh is saying that the host name is different to the server name, even when its on the same computer, which could be where your problem is stemming from, as youre hitting the right computer when there is one adapter, but when there is more than one its got no idea what the frig youre on about

Comment: @RhysW that is effectively my point.  If you have a single server MY_APPSERVER and several clients, they all need to talk to MY_APPSERVER, but if you are only supplying them with their own hostnames, they'll never be able to locate the server.

Comment: Interesting, the distinction between host name and server name is news to me. Where could I find documentation for this? I have been operating under the assumption that the host name and the server name are the same thing. In this particular scenario, however, the machine I want to talk to is the local host, and that's what I thought Dns.GetHostName() did.

Comment: John i guess youve been very lucky up to this point XD think of it this way computer can host more than one server, if you give it a host name its basically saying hey code im thinking of a number in the 20's tell me which one, then its got all 10 choices to make from, and as c# wont make assumptions for you itll get to a fork in the road and take neither,

gethostname does what it says on the tin, get me the name of the host of this server

Comment: I understand that a machine can host more than one server, but aren't those servers distingished by their TCP ports (in the case of TCP services)? That is, I can talk to a service on a machine provided I have its name (host name) which can resolve to an IP address, and a TCP port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Socket.Bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx):

> Before calling `Bind`, you must first create the local `IPEndPoint` from which you intend to communicate data. If you do not care which local address is assigned, you can create an `IPEndPoint` using `IPAddress.Any` as the address parameter, and the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network address. *This might help simplify your application if you have multiple network interfaces.*

(emphasis added). So that would be one suggested change.

I'd also suggest switching your `Connect` call to [`Connect(string,int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7ew360f.aspx):

> Establishes a connection to a remote host. The host is specified by a host name and a port number.

(a `host` value of `'localhost'` should be sufficient there)

That is, get rid of all of this mucking about with DNS, etc, and just rely on the underlying infrastructure to resolve these issues.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the IPAddress.Any option for Bind(). It looks like a likely candidate for a solution. I'll tinker with it and see whether it resolves the issue.

Comment: Indeed, this was the right thing to do. Thanks for your help!